# How does this lambda function work in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
pairs = [(1, 'one'), (2, 'two'), (3, 'three'), (4, 'four')]
pairs.sort(key=lambda pair: pair[1])

print(pairs)
```

#### Ans:

```
[(4, 'four'), (1, 'one'), (3, 'three'), (2, 'two')]
```

How does the `pair` argument work here?

Comment: Do you understand what the `key` argument to `sort` does? Have you read the documentation? What specifically are you asking about?

Comment: FWIW, it would be better to use `key=operator.itemgetter(1)`

Comment: Something like mapping `def something(pair): return pair[1]` over each item in the list. It's not clear which part you're unsure about. The word "pair" itself has no specific meaning, call it whatever you like.

Comment: @roganjosh get it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to sort a collection, the `key` parameter is a function that is used to extract from each element the value by which you want to sort. The function takes the argument, produces a value, and uses this value to sort the list

In your case, `lambda pair: pair[1]`, is just an anonymous function that takes your `(x, y)` pairs of values and returns only the `y`. Since those values are strings in your case, your list is sorted in alphabetical order of the second value of each tuple.